# How to interpret a variable having a negative %IncMSE in Random Forest?

Tags: r, random-forest

As far as I understood, a variable having a negative *%IncMSE* is not significant for the model, right?

If so, should I exclude from the model and perform a new (revised) *randomForest* application? The results of my model is as follows:

```
%IncMSE IncNodePurity
Newline 39.87 0.26
Market 19.91 0.13
Period 19.87 0.14
Cap_Exp_Cost -15.11 0.16
Profitability 23.08 0.28
Unit_Cap_Usage 44.51 0.53
Capacity 59.87 0.63
```